# Stream data to velocity template on the fly

Tags: java, velocity

Could someone let me know, if it is possible to open somehow Velocity Excel template and stream to it partially a bigger amount of data on the fly?

Let say I would like to read in a loop from external resource ArrayLists with data. One list with 10 000 items per each iteration. In simple iteration I would like to push the list to Velocity Excel template and forget about it by jumping to the next iteration. At the end of data processing I would do a final merge the Velocity context and template with all data.

So far, I've seen ways of generating Excel reports by Velocity engine in a few simple steps:

- create Velocity template
- create Velocity context
- put data to context
- merge context and template

but I need to repeate 3th step several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I see with default Velocity would be to implement something like a "streaming Collection" which never holds the complete data in memory, but rather provides the data in the iterator one by one.

You would then put this Collection into the Velocity context and use it in the Velocity Template to iterate over the items. Internally the Collection would retrieve the items in the hasNext()/next() call one after the other from your external source.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my tested solution that works well in my case. I'm able to generate to Excel sheet a huge amout of data loaded directly from database.

```
Connection conn = getDs().getConnection();
// such a configuration of prepared statement is mandatory for large amount of data
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(MY_QUERY, ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);

// load huge amount of data per 50000 items
ps.setFetchSize(50000);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

// calculate count of returned data earlier
final CountWrapper countWrapper = new CountWrapper(countCalculatedEarlier);
CustomResultSetIterator<MyObject> rowsIter = new CustomResultSetIterator<MyObject>(rs, new org.apache.commons.dbutils.BasicRowProcessor(), MyObject.class) {

    private Long iterCount = 0L;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // you can't call isLast method on defined as forward only cursor of result set, hence there is a homegrown calculation whether last item is reached or not
        return iterCount < countWrapper.getCount().longValue();
    };

    @Override
    public MyObject next() {
        iterCount++;
        return super.next();
    };
};

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
// place an interator here instead of collection object
context.put("rows", rowsIter);

Template t = ve.getTemplate(template);
File file = new File(parthToFile);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
// generate on the fly in my case 1 000 000 rows in Excel, watch out such an Excel may have 1GB size
t.merge(context, fw);

// The CustomResultSetIterator is a:

public class CustomResultSetIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
  //...implement all interface's methods
}
```